If ($\mathbb{P} \ \text{is c.c.c.})^M$ then $\mathbb{P}$ preserves cardinals.
In "Old Kunen", we have that a partial order $\mathbb{P}$ preserves cardinals $$\iff \forall \beta \in o(M)[\beta > \omega \land (\beta \ \text{is a cardinal})^M \to (\beta \ \text{is a cardinal})^{M[G]}]. \qquad (1)$$
Kunen claims that if $M$ believes that $\mathbb{P}$ has the countable chain condition, i.e. $(\mathbb{P} \ \text{is c.c.c.})^M$, then this follows from the following lemma (by taking $B = \beta$ and $A = \alpha$ for $\alpha < \beta \land \alpha \in \mathbf{ON}$):

Assume $\mathbb{P} \in M$, $(\mathbb{P} \ \text{is c.c.c.})^M$, $A,B \in M$; let $G$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$, and assume that $f:A \to B$ with $f \in M[G]$. Then there is a map $F:A \to \mathscr{P}(B)$ with $F \in M$, $\forall a \in A(f(a) \in F(a))$ and $\forall a \in A((|F(a)| \leq \omega)^M)$.

Now, my reasoning is the following: If we assume the contrapositive of $(1)$, then there is some smaller ordinal $\alpha$ so that we have an isomorphism $f:\alpha \to \beta$ in $M[G]$. Then by the lemma above, there is some $F:\alpha \to \mathscr{P}(\beta)$ with the properties given above. Is this $F$ then an isomorphism, or can we restrict/corestrict $F$ so that we get an isomorphism?

No, the idea is that the range of $f$ is contained in $\bigcup_{\gamma < \alpha}F(\gamma)$ which is union of $|\alpha|$-many countable subsets of $\beta$.

Right; it then follows that $\text{ran}(f) = \beta \subset \bigcup\limits_{\gamma < \alpha}(F(\gamma)$, and we (by 10.21, I) have $|\beta| \leq \left|\bigcup\limits_{\gamma < \alpha}(F(\gamma)\right| \leq \alpha$, so $\beta$ is not a cardinal. This is atleast under the assumption that $(\alpha < \beta)^{M[G]} \rightarrow (\alpha < \beta)^{M}$.

Yes, (or to be precise, what we need is $\beta$ is not a cardinal in $M$... note your $|\beta|\le \alpha$ statement is in $M$, which is important, and it's where we make use of the fact that $F\in M$). Yes, $\alpha < \beta$ is absolute (recall it is defined as $\alpha\in \beta$). Note also this can be adapted pretty straightforwardly to show the stronger statement that regularity is preserved as well.

Oh, yes $(\alpha < \beta)^M \leftrightarrow (\alpha < \beta) \leftrightarrow (\alpha < \beta)^{M[G]}$ since both $M$ & $M[G]$ are models for $\sf{ZFC}$.
